# Mold or precipitate on houseplant soil? Yellow peaks in soil clump tops

Tags: identification, houseplants, fungus, potting-soil, dracaena

Ever since I got my 2nd hand dragon tree, the soil has had these yellowish peaks. Until today, I never really thought about them.

However, I added some new soil on the old about a week ago. The yellow peaks seem to be already appearing. It is also on the ceramic pot.

So far I had attributed them to calcium deposits from evaporation, but Google rather proposed yellow slime mold. I have never seen any real fungal activity in the pots.

This happens also in the 2nd generation of the plants, i.e. with cuttings.

Here are a couple of photos from a pot where some cuttings are growing.

[image: soil in a pot]
[image: more soil in a pot]

What do you think these yellowish things are?

Comment: I failed to upload the photos due to an access token error. Please feel free to upload them in-line.

Comment: A duplicate? https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1562/my-indoor-plant-has-an-orange-mold-like-substance-growing-on-it-and-has-tiny-whi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just showed my plants to two professional plant caretakers. They said that it certainly is not mold/fungus, but precipitate. Mold or Fungus would also have a distinctive smell.

I also saw a while ago some other dragon trees with the same precipitate.

Answer (score 1):

These are mold or fungi that are eating the organic matter in the soil less mix which will have a higher percentage of bark and peat than soil in the garden.

All they need to get going is wet soil. They do no harm to the plant.

You can use a chopstick or old fork to break up the top of the soil and try and keep the plant a little drier.  Dragon tree or Dracaena reflexa var. angustifolia ([Dracaena marginata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_reflexa)) is easy to overwater and best cultivated with more light and less water